# Maven dependency lib path

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

I have created the sample maven project and it executes well as expected, however I would like to know the location of JUnit library.

I tried to find it in the local repository and my project path but I do not find the one.

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.maven.sample</groupId>
    <artifactId>sampleproject</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>sampleproject</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Maven version: 3.3.9.

Comment: did you look into your local maven cache (.m2 folder), .m2/repository/junit/junit/3.8.1 folder?

Comment: oh.. yup i found it under user\.m2\repository\junit\junit, So, maven will place all the dependency under user lovel repository ? i thought it will be copied/placed under local repository(%M2_HOME%\conf directory)

Comment: No, that is the maven installation folder and its configuration subfolder, not the repository

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file is certainly in your Maven cache, in the `.m2/repository/junit/junit/3.8.1` folder, note the pattern: `.m2/repository/<groupId>/<artifactId>/<version>`

If you really want to have it automatically generated by Maven, use the [Maven Dependency Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/) and its [build-classpath](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/build-classpath-mojo.html) goal.

From the command line on your project run:

```
mvn dependency:build-classpath
```

It will generate as part of the build output a list of paths for all the declared dependencies, so you will be sure where to look for.

Additionally, you can use the `mdep.outputFile` option to have it written to a file:

```
mvn dependency:build-classpath -Dmdep.outputFile=classpath.txt
```